# KeyError:0 when using a python script to read and convert Gmsh output to a DNS code session file

Tags: python, dns, mesh, keyerror, traceback

When i run the python script on the Gmsh output file I get the below error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ali/bin/gmsh2sem.py", line 289, in <module>
    surflines += "\t% 4i % 4i %i <B> %s </B>\n" % (i, elmt+1, edge+1, Phys[physidx][0])
KeyError: 0
```

the part of python code it's referring to is:

```
  if len(Phys):
    # -- SURFACES section from read BC
    #    Now that we know all quads, we can match BC to surfaces
    #    FIXME: surfaces list is unsorted
    surflines = ""
    i = 0
    for line in rawsurf:
        words = line.split()
        physidx = int(words[version.physidx_col])
        try:
            elmt, edge = find_element_and_edge(Elements, int(words[-2]), int(words[-1]))
            i += 1
            surflines += "\t% 4i % 4i %i <B> %s </B>\n" % (i, elmt+1, edge+1, Phys[physidx][0])
        except ValueError:
            sys.stderr.write("ignoring unmatched nodes %s" % line)
```

any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The problem is in `Phys[physidx][0]`. A KeyError usually means you're accessing a key in a dictionary which isn't there. So I think the problem is with the last `[0]`

Comment: Thanks @AnkitKumar any solution?,
 I've tried replacing:
`except ValueError:
            sys.stderr.write("ignoring unmatched nodes %s" % line)`
with `except KeyError:
          continue`
as it was suggested for a similar issue on 'Quora' , but then in the output the whole 'SURFACES section' was missing, which is the section that this bit of the code is supposed to create from reading the Gmsh output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your above snippet I am assuming values of `physidx` will be of type int.

```
physidx = 0
Phys = {1: []
        }

print(Phys[physidx][0])
```

Output:

```
    print(Phys[physidx][0])
KeyError: 0
```

So now

#### case #1: if you just want to handle exception you can add `KeyError` along with `ValueError` in exception statement and take necessary action.

```
try:
    print(Phys[physidx][0])
except (ValueError,KeyError) as err:
    print("Key error ", err)
```

#### case #2: If you have some default value in your mind then you go with `.get` method.

```
print(Phys.get(physidx, [{"default value"}])[0])
# output on missing key
# {'default value'}
```

Comment: Thanks @Shakeel your "case #2" suggestion was what I needed, changing to `Phys.get([physidx][0]))` fixed the problem!